# MySQL query is not executing with error code 1064?

Tags: mysql

I'm a noob in SQL,i tried seeking some answers here,but couldn't figure out why,this is the query i'm trying to execute,i didn't write it,just trying to do someone else's work,please can someone tell me why this is not working ?

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a full error message?

Comment: Is this really mySQL or is it MSFT SQL Server? (they aren't the same)  in MSFT SQL Server it compiles fine: http://rextester.com/NVJ9716  or http://rextester.com/IIY75078 to show some data.  The use of DBO and []'s around names implies this code is MSFT SQL Server;  yet you tagged this as mySQL on which this wouldn't work.  So on which DBMS platform do you need this to work?

Comment: @Myonara Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(  MigrationId nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,  ContextKey nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,  Mode' at line 1

Comment: @xQbert I'm not sure,could you confirm ??

Comment: No, we can't confirm.  You have to be able to define which database product you're using.  Each may implement their version of standard ANSI SQL but they all have variations.    If you run `select @@version as 'sql server version'` what is returned?  if you run `select version() as 'mysql version'` what is returned?  one of these should work. the one that does tells us if you're using mySQL or SQL server.

Comment: @xQbert I'm using mySQL ,but i'm not sure if the above code is SQL Server or mySQL

Comment: I've never seen mySQL use []'s.  dbo I usually see in MSAccess and SQL Server.  the fact that it compiles on MSFT SQL server and not mySQL implies it's built for SQL server, not mySQL.  The syntax would have to be changed to support mySQL.

Comment: LOL,you have no clue as to how glad i am,to learn that the above code is SQL server and not mySQL is priceless for me :P

Comment: `CREATE TABLE AspNetRoles(
    Id   nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT AspNetRoles PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Id ASC
))` works for mySQL  if all you need to do is have a table with a PK and two columns.  I do find it odd to see AspNetRoles as a table name in mySQL though.